# Maven Cargo: Weblogic deploy pingURL timesout

Tags: maven, deployment, maven-cargo, cargo-maven2-plugin

I have configured the `cargo` plugin to deploy to an already running local installation of `weblogic`.

When I run `mvn cargo:deploy` I can see it copies the `war` to the autodeploy directory of the weblogic domain, I can then in my web browser go the same URL it's attempting to ping and display the welcome page.

I'd like cargo to confirm the deployment has worked by using the `<pingURL>` tag, however even with a big timeout it always says failed to deploy within the timeout period!

Any ideas?

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
    <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.14</version>
    <inherited>true</inherited>
    <configuration>
        <container>
            <containerId>weblogic121x</containerId>
            <type>installed</type>
            <home>${weblogic121x.home}</home>
        </container>
        <configuration>
            <type>existing</type>
            <home>${weblogic121x.home}/domains/${weblogic121x.domain}</home>
            <properties>
                <cargo.hostname>${weblogic121x.host}</cargo.hostname>
                <cargo.weblogic.administrator.user>${weblogic121x.user}</cargo.weblogic.administrator.user>
                <cargo.weblogic.administrator.password>${weblogic121x.password}</cargo.weblogic.administrator.password>
                <cargo.logging>high</cargo.logging>
                <cargo.servlet.port>${weblogic121x.adminport}</cargo.servlet.port>
            </properties>
        </configuration>
        <deployables>
            <deployable>
                <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                <type>war</type>
                <properties>
                    <context>${sit.context}</context>
                </properties>
                <location>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.${project.packaging}</location>
                <pingURL>http://${weblogic121x.host}:${weblogic121x.adminport}${sit.context}</pingURL>
                <pingTimeout>150000</pingTimeout>
            </deployable>
        </deployables>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to run maven build with -X flag? Try to look for URLDeployableMonitor debug log in console. It should show what Cargo is doing and why ping failed.

Comment: I did actually try this and it kept repeating a watchdog message that essentially said "not deployed yet". It keeps doing this until the timeout expires. No other apparent error/exception

Comment: Is your ping URL correct? In your configuration I see ...${weblogic121x.adminport}${sit.context}...
I think there should be "/" between port and context.

Comment: Hi, yes it was correct. The `sit.context` is prefixed with a /

Comment: Hi, can you please put here what message Cargo shows when trying to access that URL?

Comment: Can you try to put context value without / prefix into <context> element?